# the first time vs. for the first time

Tags: prepositions, comparison, prepositional-phrases

> A. I got lost when I came here the first time.
>
> B. I got lost when I came here **for** the first time.

Which one is correct? Or is there any semantic difference between them?

Comment: A related question at ELU: [Is it common to omit a preposition (in / on / of) before “the month (year / week /day) when they are used adjectively and adverbially?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111217/is-it-common-to-omit-a-preposition-in-on-of-before-the-month-year-week)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess both are correct, and their meaning is the same, or largely the same. I don't notice any difference.

The first sentence may sound a bit less formal.

Strangely, when I reword the sentence, I feel the need for the preposition:

> Coming here **for** the first time, I got lost.

But maybe here it is also okay to drop the preposition.

From the grammar standpoint, "for the first time" is an *adverbial prepositional phrase*: it modifies the verb *to come* as a adverb would do. It serves as an "adverbial complement to the verb *came*" (in your example sentence).